# Spring Boot | Upload an image to relative path in resources

Tags: spring, file-upload, spring-boot, image-uploading, relative-path

I get "System can't find the path specified." when I try to upload an image to project folder inside resources.
Here is my project structure:

|Project
  |src
    |main
      |resources
         |META-INF.resources
            |images

[Project Structural Hierarchy can be seen here in the image format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM2ZP.png)

I have defined the path as

```
String path = "\\resources\\images\\" + imageName; File file = new File(path );
    try {
        InputStream is = event.getFile().getInputstream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path );
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0)
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        is.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

What can be the exact path to images folder under META-INF.resources directory?

Comment: Did you try  ` ServletContext `?

Comment: `String path = context.getRealPath("resources/images" + imageName);` should work after you get `ServletContext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work fine:

```
//App.java 
    String path = "\\META-INF.resources\\images\\" + imageName;
    InputStream is = App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(

                    path);
```

In a nut shell, use "getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()" instead of FileInputStream or FileOutputStream.

Comment: \META-INF.resources\images\  didn't work actually for my case.

Comment: Isn't it a maven project?

Comment: Yes. It's a maven project. But i'm still facing "System can not find the path specified."

Comment: yes your right I can replicate your issue, I have changed my answer please try it.

Comment: Thanks @Shaik Elias for your help. It was intelliJ showing the project directory as META-INF.resources as single directory name. But when I go into project structure via explorer META-INF was a separate folder and resources was its child folder. Your previous suggestion worked for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me.
In application.properties I defined my path string as:

`image.path = src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/images/uploads/`

Here is my uploadImage function in a class file.

```
 @Autowired
private Environment environment;

public String uploadImg(FileUploadEvent event, String imagePrefix) {

    String path = environment.getProperty("image.path");

    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    String name = fmt.format(new Date())
            + event.getFile().getFileName().substring(
            event.getFile().getFileName().lastIndexOf('.'));
    name = String.format("%s%s" ,imagePrefix ,name );
    String finalPath = String.format("%s%s" ,path ,name);
    System.out.println("image is going to save @ " +finalPath);

    File file = new File(finalPath).getAbsoluteFile();

    try {
        InputStream is = event.getFile().getInputstream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0)
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        is.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return name;
}
```

I am not sure whether it will work at production or not. Basically I get absolute path of the project and then append my relatively extracted path. Correct me if I am wrong.